# Get plugin directory from a theme

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Does anyone know a non-hacky way of getting the plugin directory path from within a theme's functions.php?

I've used plugin_dir_path(**FILE**), but because its called in the theme's functions.php it returns the path to that file. Not the plugins directory. I could string manipulate it and add the plugins path, but that feels nearly as bad as hardcoding the whole path.

I have got it working using:

```
require_once( ABSPATH .'/wp-content/plugins/ehu-events/event-widget.php' );
```

But I know that's so oldschool and wrong and I'd probably be shunned from the wordpress community for using it!

Is there a standard wordpress function I can use for this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe what you're looking for is :

```
WP_PLUGIN_DIR  // full path, no trailing slash
WP_PLUGIN_URL  // full url, no trailing slash
```

See [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories)

Comment: Keep in mind that there're filters that might move the location somewhere else. This might be best bet, but it's surely not a save assumption.

Comment: The linked documentation says the following about the constants: «These should not be used directly by plugins or themes, but are listed here for completeness.» So it probably shouldn’t be suggested as the solution, when the advice is to **not** use them in your theme.

Answer (score 11):

I believe this may be more reliable than depending upon the constants.

```
$url = plugins_url();
$path = parse_url($url);
var_dump($path['path']);
```

The reason I suspect it may be more reliable is that the [`plugins_url` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) considers both the `WPMU_PLUGIN_URL` and the `WP_PLUGIN_URL` constants and will also respect the [`plugins_url`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/link-template.php#L2089) filter.

Comment: This is the most non-hacky method and it should be the best answer.

Comment: what about plugins contained within themes?

Comment: ... and then use `untrailingslashit( get_home_path() ) . $path['path']` to get the full server path.